# Issue when inserting content into DOM element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to insert some content into a specific DOM element using JavaScript's innerHTML, but I keep getting an

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined

error. Unfortunately, I can't directly edit the HTML to resolve this. The error message points to the line where I attempt to set the innerHTML property of the element. I've made sure to select the element correctly using querySelector and getElementsByClassName, but the error persists.

I suspect that the element might not exist at the time of execution or there could be some issue with my code placement. Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="banners-extras banners-vitrine-mini">
  <div class="conteiner">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <li class="banner-extra banner-vitrine-mini" style="opacity: 1;">
        <img src="https://img.jpg" alt="Moda intima vitrine-mini" draggable="false">
      </li>
      <li class="banner-extra banner-vitrine-mini">
        <img src="https://img2.jpg" alt="Moda resort vitrine-mini" draggable="false">  
      </li>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // Get the first element with the classes "banner-extra" and "banner-vitrine-mini"
    const targetElement = document.querySelector('.banner-extra.banner-vitrine-mini');

    // Set the innerHTML of the target element to the desired text content
    const textContent = 'This is the text to be inserted';
    targetElement.innerHTML = textContent;
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Pasting your code into a stack snippet works perfectly. We need more context because the code you have on this question works without any errors and gives the expected output

Comment: The code snippet has the element in the HTML. In your actual application, do you create the element dynamically with JS?

Comment: There is nothing in that snippet that could throw that error (unless something did modify `document.querySelector`). If the element wasn't found, it would tell that `targetElement` is `null`, not `undefined`. Check again the trace of the error and see where it comes from, it's certainly not from *this* script. (The most plausible explanation being that your browser didn't run *this* script but an other one where you had a typo.)